# How do I install my Comodo SSL cert in Google Compute Engine?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, google-compute-engine

The `gcloud` command does not work since I am not in the Alpha testing for HTTPS load balancing.

How do I manually install a Comodo SSL certificate in my Google Compute Engine instance.

I am running a WordPress e-commerce website.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the standard WordPress tutorial for setting up SSL and HTTPS, e.g., [this one](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-ssl-and-https-in-wordpress/). This question is not GCE-specific.

Comment: The requester asked how to manually install a SSL certificate on Compute Engine, that link assumes the SSL certificate file(s) have been installed and configured.